# Lectura con fstream, archivo .txt

Tags: c++, fstream

Tengo que leer un archivo .txt y me debería salir igual al archivo claro, pero todo sale con salto de linea, no puedo usar el string para hacer eso.

```
fstream fichero;
char texto[200];
// Abro para lectura
fichero.open("Partidas.txt", ios::in);
fichero >> texto;           // Leo una primera linea
while (!fichero.eof())      // Mientras se haya podido leer algo
{
    cout << texto << endl;    // Muestro lo que lei
    fichero >> texto;         // Y vuelvo a intentar leer
}
fichero.close();            // Finalmente, cierro
getch();
```

Estoy intentando usar así, como he demostrado arriba, pero me sale así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Puedes leer carácter a carácter sin usar `std::string` usando iteradores:

```
// Los flujos de archivo son implícitamente convertibles a booleano,
// si el archivo no se puede abrir, la expresión se evalúa como 'false'.
if (std::ifstream p{"Partidas.txt"})
{
    // Un alias para acceder al iterador con mayor facilidad (opcional).
    using it = std::istream_iterator<char>;

    // Queremos que nos lea también los espacios en blanco (NO SKIP White Spaces).
    p >> std::noskipws;

    // Iteramos el flujo de archivo 'p'
    for (it b{p}, e{}; b != e; ++b)
        std::cout << *b;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY/NTsMwEITP8VMM4ZLSgvi5NWlu3EDiDdDGcYJFY5u1zV@UZw9pUgQSB06rHc3sfiOdO2@lHMdTbeQ@1gqFtj6woq4UP1rzV9JBMQXLpRDaBHSkTbYSvUh0g8yHeru1xxRcnz4QB12TvwjvIR1WIpmMiUNRIL01iAb72BJjOnxHuCcjn2hz2GT8sDC2q1hNAy9RK7Ygabkm7hSucI0bsPLOmppgAxNe1Weai2QQv1j0fyzRa9NCB@ywBBb/43fNYiLiMhczdlkuJmP9s3ZvfpYby8imA1Xvhg1UP@SocLKDyrFeV9ObJJlD0sZwKH5WHSFZhcgGl7kYxvEL)</kbd>.

Comment: Pero no podrías trabajar lo línea por línea, mejor es un getline(). Me parece La solución es buena si solo quieres ver el archivo tal cual. En la pregunta hay un comentario que dice lee primera línea.

Comment: Por favor edita tu respuesta  porque quise darle votación a favor y se fue al contrario. Me parece como dije la solución es buena. No me deja corregir la votación si no editas.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich obviamente puedo trabajarlo línea a línea, pero entendí que la persona que preguntó no quería eso.

Comment: Gracias, siento no haber puesto claramente.

Comment: @LuísFilipe entonces, ¿te sirve lo que mostré?

Comment: Si, pero veo muy complejo para yo que estoy empezando en la universidad. Crees que si uso un getline con un char arraway seria mejor?

Comment: Sería una opción, pero es incompatible con tus limitaciones: ninguna sobrecarga de [`std::getline`](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) soporta formaciones de `char`.

Comment: archivo_partidas.getline(linea, 200);    la uso así y me salio bien

Comment: Me parece raro, pero si te funcionó ¡genial! n_n